# How do I tell if a column in a pandas dataframe is of type datetime? How do I tell if a column is numerical?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to filter the columns in a pandas dataframe based on whether they are of type date or not.  I can figure out which ones are, but then would have to parse that output or manually select columns.  I want to select date columns automatically.  Here's what I have so far as an example - I'd want to only select the 'date_col' column in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Feb-2017', 1, 2],
                   ['Mar-2017', 1, 2],
                   ['Apr-2017', 1, 2],
                   ['May-2017', 1, 2]], 
                  columns=['date_str', 'col1', 'col2'])
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_str'])
df.dtypes
```

Out:

```
date_str            object
col1                 int64
col2                 int64
date_col    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pandas has a cool function called `select_dtypes`, which can take either exclude or include (or both) as parameters.  It filters the dataframe based on dtypes.  So in this case, you would want to include columns of dtype `np.datetime64`.  To filter by integers, you would use `[np.int64, np.int32, np.int16, np.int]`, for float: `[np.float32, np.float64, np.float16, np.float]`, to filter by numerical columns only: `[np.number]`.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64])
```

Out:

```
    date_col
0   2017-02-01
1   2017-03-01
2   2017-04-01
3   2017-05-01
```

In:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

Out:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       2
1   1       2
2   1       2
3   1       2
```

Comment: This is filtering. How do you check if the col is actually datetime types where it would only output boolean True False?

Answer (score 81):

I just encountered this issue and found that @charlie-haley's answer isn't quite general enough for my use case. In particular `np.datetime64` doesn't seem to match `datetime64[ns, UTC]`.

```py
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_str'], utc=True)
print(df.date_str.dtype)  # datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

You could also extend the list of dtypes to include other types, but that doesn't seem like a good solution for future compatability, so I ended up using the `is_datetime64_any_dtype` function from the pandas api instead.

In:

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype as is_datetime

df[[column for column in df.columns if is_datetime(df[column])]]
```

Out:

```py
                   date_col
0 2017-02-01 00:00:00+00:00
1 2017-03-01 00:00:00+00:00
2 2017-04-01 00:00:00+00:00
3 2017-05-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Even though it strictly is correct, I would like to point out that this solution does not detect `datetime.date` fields

Answer (score 4):

bit uglier Numpy alternative:

```
In [102]: df.loc[:, [np.issubdtype(t, np.datetime64) for t in df.dtypes]]
Out[102]:
    date_col
0 2017-02-01
1 2017-03-01
2 2017-04-01
3 2017-05-01

In [103]: df.loc[:, [np.issubdtype(t, np.number) for t in df.dtypes]]
Out[103]:
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     2
2     1     2
3     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I needed to check if any element of a column was a date or numeric

My approach was, try to convert to type (datetime or numeric), then check if any element is null

```
pd.to_datetime( data_temp.eval('col_name'), format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
0   2010-09-16
1   2010-09-16
2   2018-06-04
3          NaT
4          NaT
5   2018-11-30
```

Then use `isnull()` to check if the elements could be converted

```
pd.to_datetime( data_temp.eval('col_name'), format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').isnull().any()
```

This will return **True** because at last one element is null/NaT

To check for numerics

```
data_temp.eval('col_name').astype(str).str.isnumeric().all()
```

This will return **True** if all elements on the column are numeric

Both will return a **numpy.bool_**, but it can easily be converted to bool if needed

```
type(pd.to_datetime( data_temp.eval(name), format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').isnull().any())
```

output:

```
numpy.bool_
```

--

```
type(bool(pd.to_datetime( data_temp.eval(name), format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce').isnull().any()))
```

output:

```
bool
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for datetime which have timezone info into it. Here I am converting a datetime object (initially stored as object), first into a datetime, then I am localizing it.

my initial datetime value looks like this

> 2021-06-15 23:35:00+05:30

```python
for i,j in zip(data.dtypes.index,data.dtypes.values):
    if type(j) ==  pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype:
        data[i] = pd.to_datetime(data[i],utc=True)
        data[i] = data[i].dt.tz_convert(tz='Asia/Kolkata')
        data[i] = data[i].dt.tz_localize(tz=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code automatically identify the date column and change datatype from object to 'datetime64[ns]'. Once you got date datatype you can easily perform other operations.

```
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype == 'object':
        try:
            data[col] = pd.to_datetime(data[col])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: Nope. If you have a column of only null values, those would be converted to dates too.